# Europa type free alternative

Tags: fonts, free

I downloaded a logo in .ai format and the text isn't in outlines.
I know that the text should be in Europa font, but I don't have it
What is the closest free font to Europa ?

Comment: could you please post a screenshot of Europa?

Answer (score 2):

The closest alternatives would be Avenir or Sailec and the best free alternative would be Nunito [which can be found on Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nunito).

Answer (score 1):

Europa is a web font available in Adobe Typekit. So if you have an Adobe CC subscription, then you can install it for free.

In Illustrator CC click *Type > Add Fonts from Typekit*

When your browser opens, in the Search Typekit box, type Europa. From tbe Europa page you can choose to *Sync All* to get all 6 fonts in the family, or you can choose to sync individual ones.